# Is where anywhere list of "allowed" characters for the Defect name?

Tags: java, rally

I tried to create a Defect in Rally with this name - between quotes:
"Assertion Error in '<'Verify the login with UI toolkit 2.1 sample web app.'>'"
Unfortunately it saves only the "Assertion Error in "
Why the rest cannot be saved and why Rally does not give any warning if I am using illegal characters in the name?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have not come across a list of characters that are not expected to work, but generally in a context of a request using angle brackets introduce ambiguity because the intention is not clear if the user meant to add an html tag.  I was able to create defects with angle brackets  in the same name you used by replacing the brackets with less than and greater than equivalents as in:

`Assertion Error in &lt;Verify the login with UI toolkit 2.1 sample web app.&gt;`

Here is my Java code written with with [Java REST Toolkit](https://github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitForJava).

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException, IOException {
        String host = "https://rally1.rallydev.com";
        String username = "user@co.com";
        String password = "test";
        String projectRef = "/project/1791267822";
            String applicationName = "RestExample_createDefect";


        RallyRestApi restApi = new RallyRestApi(
                new URI(host),
                username,
                password);
        restApi.setApplicationName(applicationName);   

        try {
            for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
                JsonObject newDefect = new JsonObject();
                newDefect.addProperty("Name", "Assertion Error in &lt;Verify the login with UI toolkit 2.1 sample web app.&gt;");
                newDefect.addProperty("Project", projectRef); 
                CreateRequest createRequest = new CreateRequest("defect", newDefect);
                CreateResponse createResponse = restApi.create(createRequest);  
                if (createResponse.wasSuccessful()) {
                System.out.println(String.format("Created %s", createResponse.getObject().get("_ref").getAsString()));          
                    String ref = Ref.getRelativeRef(createResponse.getObject().get("_ref").getAsString());
                    System.out.println(String.format("\nReading Defect %s...", ref));
                    GetRequest getRequest = new GetRequest(ref);           
                } else {
                String[] createErrors;
                createErrors = createResponse.getErrors();
                    System.out.println("Error occurred creating a defect: ");
                for (int j=0; i<createErrors.length;j++) {
                    System.out.println(createErrors[j]);
                }
                }
            }
        } finally {
            restApi.close();
        }   
    }   
}
```

Comment: Actually I was trying to enter the text without single quotes around < or >. It does not work.

Comment: Hi Stella. I used quotes because your example had quotes around angle brackets. When I remove the quotes I see exactly what you see. You are correct, the rest of the name is being chopped off. The angle brackets can be replaced with &lt; and &gt; I modified the code to reflect that.